# NoReverseMatch get_absolute_url 0 patterns tried

Tags: python, django

I get error when i go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/author/:

> NoReverseMatch at /books/author/
>
> Reverse for '/books/author/1/' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

My view is ListView and template code is below

```
<ul>
{% for author in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url author.get_absolute_url %}">{{ author.name }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

It works fine when I change my template to:

```
<ul>
{% for author in object_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'bookstore:author-details' author.pk %}">{{ author.name }} </a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My models.py contain class Author with defined get_absolute_url()

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('bookstore:author-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Main urls.py include with namespace

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^books/', include('bookstore.urls', namespace='bookstore')),
]
```

Here is bookstore.urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^author/', include([
        url(r'^$', views.AuthorsList.as_view(), name='authors-list'),
        url(r'^create/', views.AuthorCreate.as_view(), name='author-create'),
        url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/', include([
            url(r'^$', views.AuthorDetails.as_view(), name='author-details'),
            url(r'edit/', views.AuthorEdit.as_view(), name='author-edit'),
            url(r'delete/', views.AuthorDelete.as_view(), name='author-delete'),
    ]))
    ])),
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up two methods, namely:

`{% url "routing-name" arguments %}`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

and

`reverse("routing-name", [arguments])`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Both these methods return a string that represents the address of a certain routing ('/books/author/1/' in your case).

What you are trying to do now is feed the result of `reverse()` to the `url` function. Literarily this results in `{% url '/books/author/1/' %}`. Now Django complains that the routing '/books/author/1/' does not exist.

Solution: `{{ author.get_absolute_url }}`.

Answer (score 0):

self.pk is an integer and you need to have a string.

Change :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('bookstore:author-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

to :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('bookstore:author-details', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})
```

Also it is possible to use args instead :

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('bookstore:author-details', args=[str(self.pk)])
```

Comment: No this is wrong. [0-9]+ in the url-patterns requests for one or more digits. It does not matter if you provide an int or string, as long as your provide one or more digits.

Comment: @WouterKleinHeerenbrink, For what do django docs have str in their docs then?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url

Comment: Fair point... I don't know...! Fact is that it should not and does not matter if you convert the integer to a string. In order to be sure I've looked it up in the source code to see what happens. My findings:
`reverse` forwards to `_reverse_with_prefix` and this method applied a `force_text` to all `args` and `kwargs`. 
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py#L446
My conclusion: you do not have to convert it yourself

But still: fair point.. docs suggest you should.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.5+ requires quotes around the method name in the url template tag

```
{% url author.get_absolute_url %}
```

becomes

```
{% url 'author.get_absolute_url' %}
```